# Google Sheets Script, if email null then skip to next email and make a status if email are already sent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google sheets script to send an email,
how to skip a row when the email is null?
and how to create an status when the email is sent?

thank you

```
function sendMails() {
  
  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkShtEmailIDs= wrkBk.getSheetByName("recipient");
  var wrkShtMessage= wrkBk.getSheetByName("email_body");

  var subject = wrkShtMessage.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var message = wrkShtMessage.getRange('B2').getValue();

  for (var i=5;i<=100;i++){

      var emailAddress = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('C' + i).getValue();
      var finalmsg = "";
      finalmsg = "Hi " + emailAddress + "\n" + "\n" + message;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, finalmsg);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try for instance, respecting your syntax

```
function sendMails() {

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkShtEmailIDs = wrkBk.getSheetByName("recipient");
  var wrkShtMessage = wrkBk.getSheetByName("email_body");

  var subject = wrkShtMessage.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var message = wrkShtMessage.getRange('B2').getValue();

  for (var i = 5; i <= 100; i++) {

    var emailAddress = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('C' + i).getValue();

    if (emailAddress != '') {
      var finalmsg = "";
      finalmsg = "Hi " + emailAddress + "\n" + "\n" + message;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, finalmsg);
      wrkShtMessage.getRange('D' + i).setValue('sent') // status in D
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Should it be `setValue('sent')`